# JsonResult returning data, but Jquery Ajax returns undefined data when type is GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript function calling a JsonResult method, and the JsonResult method is sending the data back to the function, but when I test it with an alert in the javascript function it returns as Undefined. I have checked out a couple similar answers on SO, like this [JsonResult returns null for Jquery .ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286223/jquery-ajax-not-returning-data) and [Jquery ajax not returning data [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870984/jsonresult-returns-null-for-jquery-ajax) but they are dealing with POST and not GET, can I get some guidance on what I am doing wrong or direction to where I can this figured out?
The end result is I need to get all the returned data from the JsonResult method then populate it into textfields.

My JsonResult method is..

```
public JsonResult myResult(string id)
    {
        dal = new AWDAL();
        List<CustomerToAdd> cust = dal.GetCustomerByID(id);
        return Json(cust, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and my JavaScript is this..

```
function DataToGet(whatever) {
    alert(whatever.customerName);
}

function GetCustomerByCustomerID() {
    //var id = selectCustomerID;
    var result = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("myResult", new { id = "1234-5678-9012" })",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            return DataToGet(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I found this way of doing what I want but its for WebAPI2, I am not using WebAPI2 but it looks better, I am not even sure if I can use it to do what I want.

```
function formatItem(item) {
  return item.Name + ': $' + item.Price;
}

function find() {
  var id = $('#prodId').val();
  $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
      .done(function (data) {
        $('#product').text(formatItem(data));
      })
      .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
      });
}
```

**EDIT**
Response Header
[image: Response Header]

Response Body

[image: Response Body]

Comment: so, the questions are, can you hit a breakpoint when the function itself is called serverside, in the myResult function?  can you hit the success breakpoint in the javascript?  what occurs at both of those, the variables

Comment: @Fallenreaper, I can hit the JsonResult on serverside, but can't hit the breakpoint client side, it just automatically calls the alert

Comment: I have the GetCustomerByCustomerID being called from a selected row from a kendoui grid, I just added the ID in the GetCustomerByCustomerID because I was having an issue on passing the selected row's ID to the function

Comment: Do you receive your request in server-side action? If yes, It may be result of `cross-domain restrictions`/`Sand-box restrictions`. Your JS should be requesting from same domain. If you are not requesting to same domain, then you should use jsonp.

Comment: @abzarak, I have the JsonResult in the HomeController and it does return the data, but not getting the returned data from the javascript.Is that what you are meaning? my apologies, I am relatively new with MVC and this type of stuff, I am finding it an uphill battle moving from webforms

Comment: Also there is restrictions for XHR when you are running JS in OS file-system. I mean when you are running an HTML file from your desktop for example.

Comment: If there are restrictions wouldn't this prevent me from posting data to the database?

Comment: I seems you are requesting from the same domain so ignore my previus comments. Ok, Try this: You can do a simple trace to make sure what is the actual json response returned from server. Use firefox firebug plugin's Network tab. and investigate the http request and its response. The response should be a well-formed json and be parsed by firebug. If all these are OK, then change your jqueryjson method to a get method and receive your data as normal string. If you could do that then you have problem with jquery json parser.

Comment: No database jobs are all server-side. Sandbox restrictions are about client-server scenarios. please note that js is client-side and your mvc action is server-side. you are sendig ajax requests from client to server

Comment: I used IE instead of FireFox and added screens of the response header and body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80686/discussion-between-abzarak-and-chris).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payload is an array. To get a single item in the payload you would need to get it like so `data[0]` and each field `data[0].customerName`.

Comment: Tried, still returning the same response header and body and still throwing 'Undefined' in the alert box

Comment: update success function like so `function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` and examine each param information on what could be wrong.

Comment: I took a look at the jqXHR, and it shows that it has the customerName

Comment: is data still undefined and what about textStatus?

Comment: The data has the value, the textStatus says success, when the data is passed to my DataToGet function, the data is there, but when it gets to alert(whatever.customerName), the message in the alert box says 'undefined'

Comment: check the customerName spelling because it is case sensitive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80690/discussion-between-oluwafemi-and-chris).